# Grouping columns into count in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

So i have these 4 different cols in total in a dataframe

```
     port            ip                service      numberOfTimes
1     22         11.11.79.100            ssh           16
2     80         11.11.79.100            www           19
3     111        11.13.79.110            ipw           21
4     123        11.13.79.110            ssh           50
5     22         64.50.80.140            cde           45
6     80         64.50.80.140            www           16
7     22         71.11.64.100            ssh           234
8     80         71.11.64.100            you           33
9     22         100.15.31.1             ssh           99
10    41         120.15.31.12            has           19
```

So I have the following question:

Is it possible to group using r to the following such that it can become something like that?

**After**

```
port       ip(count of same ip)   service     numberOfTimes
 22             4                  ssh         399 (#1+#5+#7+#9)
 80             3                  www         68 (#2+#6+#8)
```

so on and so for the rest of the ports

Comment: You've already tagged `dplyr` so i assume you've come across the `group_by()` and `summarize()` functions. Did you make any attempt to solve this on your own? What code did you  write and where exactly were you getting stuck?

Comment: Hi @MrFlick To be honest. I am stucked, really stucked. 

I wanted to try dt<- dt%>% group_by(port, service) %>% summarise(numberOfTimes=sum(numberOfTimes)) but it didn't work. There was an error cannot modify grouping variable. But then again, even if i summarise them together, what happens to the IP addresses that is linked to each row? Im really stucked at how to start. because each row feels like its dependent on another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, this is quite straightforward:

```
testData %>%
  group_by(port, service) %>%
  summarise(`Number of IPs` = n_distinct(ip)
            , `Total number of times` = sum(numberOfTimes))
```

Which for the sample data you included gives:

```
   port service `Number of IPs` `Total number of times`
  <int>   <chr>           <int>                   <int>
1    22     cde               1                      45
2    22     ssh               3                     349
3    41     has               1                      19
4    80     www               2                      35
5    80     you               1                      33
6   111     ipw               1                      21
7   123     ssh               1                      50
```

If you are getting some sort of an error (alluded to in a comment), you will need to provide data that actually causes that error before people can help you.

Comment: Oh! I totally forgot about the unique and the length function for dplyr, thank you so much for the help, and yes sorry about that.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. However, neither `unique` nor `length` are from `dplyr`.

Comment: You can also use `n_distinct(ip)`, it's supposed to be faster than `length(unique(ip))`.

Comment: I always thought they are from the package, lol. Guess like i have lots to learn as well, thank you for your input @MarkPeterson

Comment: Thanks @Scarabee -- I hadn't used that, and I do this kind of counting. A big help.